# QString(const char* p) constructor misrepresents non ASCII characters

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt6

I am trying to upgrade a bigger C++ program from Qt4 to Qt5 or higher and have some problems with the legacy code that was written in ISO-LATIN1. From Qt5, the code is expected to be present in UTF8 and that is what we tried to do. We use a own String-class (let's call it `myQString` here), that was basically a `char*` under Qt4 and went to a `QString`-derived class in Qt5. So far so good.

The cases where I still have some problems is when I try to pass `char*` variables to the `myQString` class, that includes non-ASCII characters (like the letter characters with diaeresis for example, 'ä', 'Ä', 'ö', 'Ö', etc.).

I tried to write a mini program that reproduces/illustrates the problem. To make it clearer I could post some code but a picture would be better in this case:

[image: Debugger output]

[Zoom Debugger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGlHu.png)

Here we can see via the Debugger-View, that the desired end-products (cyan and yellow color: "mstr2, mstr4, qstr2, qstr4), that should be something that store "Äa", misrepresent the first byte "Ä". All of them use the green marked constructor, `myQString(const char* p)`.

The function that illustrates the problem (in the Debugger) is `charPointerToQstring()`. It is part of the file **main.cpp** (see last code block).

If you want to run that "mini" program, I will also post all the files (four) needed to do so. I am using QtCreator and have a project file, which you can call how you like, let's say "**testingQString.pro**"

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++17 console

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    myqstring.cpp

HEADERS += \
    myqstring.h
```

Then we have a "stripped" `myQString` class, with the two files:

**myqstring.h**:

```
#ifndef MYQSTRING_H
#define MYQSTRING_H

#include <QString>

class myQString : public QString
{
public:
    myQString();
    myQString(const QString& str);
    myQString(char c);
    myQString(const char* p);
    myQString(const QByteArray& ba);
};

#endif // MYQSTRING_H
```

and "stripped" **myqstring.cpp**:

```
#include "myqstring.h"

#include <QDebug>

#define ENTER_FUNCTION qDebug() << "========== Entering:" << Q_FUNC_INFO

myQString::myQString()
{
    ENTER_FUNCTION;
}

myQString::myQString(const QString& str) : QString(str)
{
    ENTER_FUNCTION;
}

myQString::myQString(char c) : QString(QChar(c))
{
    ENTER_FUNCTION;
}

myQString::myQString(const char* p) : QString(p)
{
    ENTER_FUNCTION;
}

myQString::myQString(const QByteArray& ba)
{
    ENTER_FUNCTION;
    foreach (auto c, ba) {
#if QT_VERSION_MAJOR == 5
        append(QChar(c));
#endif
#if QT_VERSION_MAJOR == 6
        append(char(c));
#endif
    }
}
```

The file **main.cpp** is also "stripped" here and only shows that one specific problem:

```
#include "myqstring.h"

#include <QDebug>

#include <array>

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void charPointerToQstring() {
    // case 1 - const char* with string as initialiser
    const char* buf1("Äa");
    myQString mstr1(buf1);
    QString   qstr1(buf1);
    
    // case 2 - char* with char assignment
    const int len = 2;
    char* buf2 = new char[len+1];
    buf2[0]   = char(0xC4); // 0xC4 == 196 == AE (umlaut)
    buf2[1]   = 'a';
    buf2[len] = '\0';
    myQString mstr2(buf2);
    QString   qstr2(buf2);

    // case 3 - str
    myQString mstr3("Äa");
    QString   qstr3("Äa");
    
    // case 4 - std::array<char>
    std::array<char, len+1> stda1;
    stda1[0] = char(0xC4);
    stda1[1]   = 'a';
    stda1[len] = '\0';
    myQString mstr4(stda1.data());
    QString   qstr4(stda1.data());
    
    qDebug() << "Set a breakpoint exactly on ME (nr 3) and check the results via Debugger!!!";
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_UNUSED(argc)
    Q_UNUSED(argv)
    
    // missing code with more tests here...
    
    charPointerToQstring();
}
```

**The big question is**: Why isn't Qt handling a single `char` of a `char*` argument right but a string as argument (with the same info) goes well? If we have a char* as an argument then we can only go for each char from 0x00 to 0xFF (unsinged). Why not make 0x**00**00 to 0x**00**FF out of it?

**Edit**:

The answer of Artyer explains the behavior for buf1 but not for buf2. buf2 is a char[3] { 0xC4, 0x61, '\0' } which get's converted (with Artyers help) to a QString with elements QChar{ 0x**00**C4, 0x**00**61 }. So Qt can easily convert those 0xC4 characters to 0x**00**C4. In fact qstr1 shows that it can convert the two chars { 0xC3, 0x84 } from 'Ä' to one correct QChar {0x**00**C4}. If we have a char* as an argument then we can only go for each char from 0x00 to 0xFF (unsinged). Why not make 0x**00**00 to 0x**00**FF out of it?
And btw, I can't accept that approach yet because it now breaks mstr1 and mstr3. They then get exactly the "same" elements as buf1 but in QChar (so, without the closing '\0', from char[3] { 0xC3, 0x84, 0x61 } to QChar { 0x**00**C3, 0x**00**84, 0x**00**61 } but it should get QChar { 0x**00**C4, 0x**00**61 })

Comment: @Adrian: Why should one remove the imgur link of the debugger? One can't see the details of the picture this way and they are necessary here...

Comment: I didn't remove any image. I merely made it so that it shows *directly*, rather than viewers having to click the link.

Comment: @Adrian: You are right, should be both in. Thx

Answer (score 0):

What is probably the case is that `"Äa"` is three UTF-8 encoded bytes in the source file (Equivalent to `char[4]{ 0xC3, 0x84, 'a', '\0' }`), and the QString constructor expects UTF-8 encoded data.

The 65533 character (U+FFFD) is the [replacement character](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qchar.html#SpecialCharacter-enum) for the invalid UTF-8 data.

Use [`QString::fromLatin1`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#fromLatin1):

```cpp
myQString::myQString(const char* p) : QString(QString::fromLatin1(p, std::strlen(p)))
{
    ENTER_FUNCTION;
}

myQString::myQString(const QByteArray& ba) : QString(QString::fromLatin1(ba))
{
    ENTER_FUNCTION;
}
```

Also consider using [`QLatin1StringView`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qlatin1stringview.html) instead of `char*` to avoid getting confused about encoding (might be called `QLatin1String` in older QT versions)